# Completely remove NERDTree from vim?

Tags: vim, plugins, installation, macvim

Basically, I have NERDTree installed in Vim (Mac OS X 10.7 Lion). I want to completely remove it.

I deleted it's files in `~/.vim/plugins/` and removed all traces of it from my `.vimrc`, but I'm still getting the following when exploring directories in MacVim:

```
Error detected while processing function Edit..ChangeDirectory:
line    4:
E492: Not an editor command:   NERDTree
```

How can I remove it from my system? I just want to use the stock directory explorer in vim. If need be, I'm willing to completely reinstall vim, I just want NERDTree out.

Comment: install pathogen plugin so you can have each plugin in a separate directory (helps next time you want to remove a plugin) https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can search all files which contains `NERDTree`, and check them.

```
$ cd /
$ grep -lr NERDTree .
```

Answer (score 3):

Those are the files that NERD Tree is made of (Github version from scrooloose):

```
doc/NERD_tree.txt
nerdtree_plugin/exec_menuitem.vim
nerdtree_plugin/fs_menu.vim
plugin/NERD_tree.vim
syntax/nerdtree.vim
```